# One word for a "cheap imitation/replica of a thing"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose I bought a fake rolex watch from a flea market. If a friend ask me, "Is it really ROLEX?". What will be a good word for "cheap imitation"?

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: imitation synonyms: clone impersonation impression mimicry parody reflection replica reproduction apery copy counterfeit counterpart ditto dupe duplicate duplication ersatz fake forgery image likeness match mime mimesis mockery parallel phony picture resemblance ringer semblance sham simulacrum takeoff transcription travesty Xerox aping carbon copy counterfeiting echoing matching mirroring paralleling paraphrasing parroting patterning representing

Comment: HotWhatever, thanks for the write-up. I have done zero research, I have heard something like this from the movie Da Vinci code. The point is, the word elude me. Can you help?

Comment: Not if you've done zero research.  Pre-researching questions such as yours is **required**.

Comment: @HotLicks: and please let me know how to research on this specific topic

Comment: Use a thesaurus.  As easy as typing `synonym imitation` on Google

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can informally use [knock off](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/knock-off?q=knockoff#nav2) (ODO)

> knock-off
>
> NOUN
>
> informal
>   A copy or imitation, especially of an expensive product:
>
> [AS MODIFIER]: knock-off merchandise

Answer (score 2):

The term  ***[fake](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fake)*** carries the connotation of "cheap imitation" you are referring to:

> - an object that is made to look real or valuable in order to deceive people:
>
>   - *Experts revealed that the painting was a fake.
>       The gun in his hand was a fake.*

- It it a Rokex or is it a fake?

Comment: I like something very British :) dont get me wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**Faux** diamonds [are a thing](https://www.google.com/search?q=faux%20diamonds&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).
The term is French for "false", but many people don't know that, and it sounds classy.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faux):

> Faux /ˈfoʊ/ is a French word for "false". The adjective has been adopted into the English language to describe an imitation or ersatz good.[1](https://www.google.com/search?q=faux%20diamonds&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

A good faux Rolex can be used to impress the rubes.